# jpa criteria api fetch on id

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I got a code in my bean like this:

```
Root<Application> root = query.from(Application.class);
Fetch<xxx, yyy> fetch = root.fetch(xxx.yyy, JoinType.LEFT);
fetch.fetch(yyy_.location, JoinType.LEFT);
fetch.fetch(yyy_.project, JoinType.LEFT);
root.fetch(xxx_.owner);
```

I need to fetch records zzz from other table, but there is no link between them in my application. 
For some records XXX are created ZZZ entrys with same ID number. I want to get them here for xxx. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add a relationship between the two or create a CriteriaQuery that will be translated to an SQL Cross Join and then add the condition `XXX.zzz_id=ZZZ.id`.

Comment: so, it's impossible to do it using criteria api?